# Android barcode detection not working for some barcodes

Tags: android, google-play-services, barcode-scanner

Using Google Play Services Barcode Detector

Performs really well with most bar codes. However, I notice that it can't detect some barcodes, for instance

"12345678" is recgonized just fine as a code-128

but "88888888" or "540" is not recognized at all as code-128

I use this site to generate barcodes:
http://barcode.tec-it.com/en

Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I tired the `visionSamples` for `barcode-reader` here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader

The `88888888` in `code-128` works, but `540` don't. I think that because `540` it too short for the `code-128`.

However, I tried the `QR code` for `540` it works great.

[image]

Comment: Hmm sounds like a bug. If I use the ZXing library, 540 works no problem https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: Yup, I tired both Nexus 5 and 9. You can report the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Comment: Does this help for you? If so, please accept, thanks